# Run the git commands inside AWS lambda(Nodejs runtime)

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, aws-lambda, version-control

We have a very different type of requirement that,
we have follow microservices and we need to have a backup of our database to a seperate a repository.
i am using aws codecommit for both lambda code and backups.

**How the Backups are creating:**
have a lambda `"GenerateLambda"` which is generate database backup, i need to deploy that file into seperate repo by cloning that repo programatically.
The steps which i follws:

- Inside the GenerateBackup lambda, i have added code for cloning the backup (Shallow cloning) using node `exec`
- Clone the backup repository to `/tmp/backups`
- Now i need to create backup ( say cron job once a day)
- Create a `backup.JSON` and i am looking run git diff /path/to/created/backup.json /tmp/backup/backup.json
- if `git diff` return non empty string i need to put the newly created file/copy the newly created file to `/tmp/backup` and run `git add.` and `git commit -m "Timestamp"` and finally `push`

I already implemented s3 way with ETag to remove duplicates, the reason which i use git, then i can track the revision or the changes very easily

want to know that, is there any better way which differs from the above steps.